# Update Shopware from 6.5.7.1 to 6.5.7.2

Tags: updates, shopware6

I have a Shopware shop which version is 6.5.7.1, it was installed via shopware-installer.phar.php file.I need to update it to 6.5.7.2 version not to last version.

I already try by setting these configs into the composer.joson file.

```json
"require": {
        "composer-runtime-api": "^2.0",
        "shopware/administration": "~v6.5.7.2",
        "shopware/core": "~v6.5.7.2",
        "shopware/elasticsearch": "~v6.5.7.2",
        "shopware/storefront": "~v6.5.7.2",
        "symfony/flex": "~2",
        "symfony/runtime": "^5.0|^6.0"
    },
```

After that I run the following commands

- bin/console system:update:prepare
- composer update
- bin/console system:update:finish

But it updated to 6.5.7.4

Answer (score 0):

The tilde operator always updates to the latest patch version of this series, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md. Remove the tilde operator and try again.

However, it is always recommended to use at least the latest patch version of a series. In the mean time, there is even version 6.5.8.2 available: https://developer.shopware.com/release-notes/6.5/6.5.8.2.html